# X={1,2,3}. Give a list of topologies on X such that every topology on X is homeomorphic to exactly one on your list.

Tags: general-topology

I'm teaching my self topology with the aid of a book. I'm trying to do the following problem:

> Let X={1,2,3}. Give a list of topologies on X such that every topology on
>   X is homeomorphic to exactly one on your list.

I'm not sure If I totally understand what is being asked, but I'm going to attempt to list every topology in groups that are homeomorphic to one another.

I want to know if this is correct.

(A) trivial topology. $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$}; I can't think of anything else that is homeomorphic to this one.

(B) "singles"

(B1): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{1}};

(B2): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{2}};

(B3): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{3}};

(C) "doubles"

(C1): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{1,2}};

(C2): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{2,3}};

(C3): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{3,1}};

(D) "single-doubles"

(D1): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{1},{1,2}};

(D2): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{1},{1,3}};

(D3): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{2},{2,1}};

(D4): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{2},{2,3}};

(D5): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{3},{3,1}};

(D6): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{3},{3,2}};

(D') "single-doubles (disjoint)"

(D'1): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{3},{1,2}};

(D'2): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{2},{1,3}};

(D'3): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{1},{2,3}};

(E) "single-single-doubles"

(E1): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{1},{2},{1,2}};

(E2): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{1},{3},{1,3}};

(E3): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{2},{3},{2,3}};

(F) "single-double-doubles"

(F1): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{1},{1,2},{1,3}};

(F2): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{2},{2,1},{3,2}};

(F3): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{3},{3,2},{3,1}};

(G) "single-single-double-doubles"

(G1): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{1},{2},{1,2},{2,3}};

(G2): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{1},{2},{1,2},{3,1}};

(G3): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{1},{3},{1,2},{3,1}};

(G4): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{1},{3},{2,3},{3,1}};

(G5): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{2},{3},{2,3},{3,1}};

(G6): $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{2},{3},{1,2},{2,3}};

(H) power set: $\mathscr{T}=${X,$\varnothing$,{1}, {2},{3},{1,2},{2,3},{3,1}};; I can't think of anything else that is homeomorphic to this one.

IS this a complete list of all topologies on X?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’re missing the ones homeomorphic to $\big\{\varnothing,X,\{1\},\{2,3\}\big\}$; there are $3$ of those. Also, your (E) group lists one topology twice: (E1) and (E3) are the same. The question wants you to list one topology from each of the $9$ groups (including the group that I just added).

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix it later.  E1 and E3 is just cause i didn't double check. But i didn't even think of {1},{2,3}.

Comment: Is {∅,X,{1},{2,3}}{∅,X,{1},{2,3}}  homeomorphic with {∅,X,{2},{2,3}}{∅,X,{1},{2,3}} ?

Comment: @Michael: $\big\{\varnothing,X,\{1\},\{2,3\}\big\}$ is homeomorphic to $\big\{\varnothing,X,\{2\},\{1,3\}\big\}$ and to $\big\{\varnothing,X,\{3\},\{1,2\}\big\}$.

Comment: So my D and D' groups are not homeomorphic to one another?

Comment: @Michael: No, they're not: the D' topologies contain a pair of non-empty open sets, and the D topologies do not. The D spaces are connected; the D' spaces are not.